# unread notification in django-private-chat

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have used `django-private-chat` for implementing one to one chat in my django project,But the problem is,it doesn't show unread message notification to user who as unread messages. I can't seem to find a way to implement this functionality.Can anyone please help me out with this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some code, otherwise it's not possible to give a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use CSS and JS to do it.And write a Model for notification which will be update every time new notification is there.